# Cannot figure out why I am getting Error: 'set' has not been declared

Tags: c++, debugging, set

I cannot for the life of me figure out why set is not declared. I have definitely #include it and can't see any reason why I would be getting this error. Any ideas?

```
myclass.h:11:22: error: 'set' has not been declared
```

My Header File: myclass.h

```
#include <string>
#include <set>

class MyClass 
{
public:
    MyClass();
    ~MyClass();
    void solve();
private:
    bool solveUtil(set<char> colors);
};
```

My Class: myclass.cpp

```
#include <iostream>
#include "myclass.h"

using namespace std;

MyClass::MyClass() {
{

MyClass::~MyClass() {
{

void MyClass::solve() {
   set<char> colors;
   cout << solveUtil(colors) << endl;
}

void MyClass::solveUtil(set<char> colors) {
    //Prints out some stuff
}
```

Comment: Keep all your includes in your .cpp file. you did `using namespace std;` after you include your header. So, stop `using namespace std;`, it is not a good practice.

Comment: If the `std::set` doesn't appear in the header, there's no reason to declare it in the header. The header is also not guarded, this will likely end up leading to a compile error.

Answer (score 1):

Use `std::set<char>` in your header file.

Answer (score 0):

Your `myclass.h` is including `<set>`, but it is not `using namespace std;` (which is good). As such, it doesn't know what `set` is, but it would know what `std::set` is:

```cpp
#include <string>
#include <set>

class MyClass 
{
public:
    MyClass();
    ~MyClass();
    void solve();
private:
    bool solveUtil(std::set<char> colors); // <-- here
};
```